# What data is coming back from Space-X's Starman and his ride?

Tags: spacex, tesla-roadster, scientific-data, telemetry

Other than the video, is any other telemetry or sensory data being beamed back to Earth for science?

Answer (score 3):

Elon Musk gave a press conference where he mentioned that it isn't returning any data. You can see the full press conference [here](https://youtu.be/sytrrdOPYzA?t=23m15s), and the question where he answers what data the car is collecting occurs at around 15:00